# Errno 22: Invalid argument: Robotframework / Python

Tags: python, logging, automation, robotframework

Issue with creating log file:

I am currently running my robot framework script using Python. Once the test suite has been executed, I get the below error message. I see the report is generated but it has some outdated information and not the most recent changes.

```
[ ERROR ] Opening log file 'C:\Users\me\folder1\folder2\folder3\log.html' failed: 
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\me\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\log.html'
```

I am using Windows system.
How to solve the above and where can I make these changes?

Your guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: do you have folder `C:\Users\me\folder1\folder2\folder3`?  Maybe you have to create it manually. Or maybe you don't have permissions to write in `log.html`. You could try in Python to open this file and write in it. It will raise error if you don't have permissions.

Comment: The file path exists. I tried writing into the file using file and got this error: Error: 
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\me\\folder1\folder2\\folder3\\log.html'

How can I resolve the permission issue of this file?

Comment: checking on the properties of the file, says I do have write permissions.

Comment: Just in case, couldn't it be the issue that the passed path has double slashes, e.g. `\\` instead of `\`?

Comment: maybe use Python to check if it can see this file - `os.path.exists(r"C:\Users")` , `os.path.exists(r"C:\Users\me")`, etc.